# Node.js 10 JSON syntax error in Google Cloud Functions: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I have a function in nodejs10 with event trigger (ref.create) on a specific path, it works because function triggers on this path normally.

Problem is, I get this error in log, and I can't solve it:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at Object.firebaseConfig (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/config.js:45:21) at resourceGetter (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/database.js:116:38) at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:116:13)
```

This is my index.js

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json"); 
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://***.firebaseio.com"
  });

exports.myFunction = admin.database().ref(<PATH>).onCreate(async (snap, context) => {.....
```

I'm deploying it based on this documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/realtime-database#deploying_your_function

and also with envars FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using the Firebase SDK, deploying with `gcloud` is fine, but I suggest that you [deploy your functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions) using the Firebase CLI.

To explain the error on your code, the correct way to create a function with a Real Time Database event is with [`functions.database`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#trigger_a_function). Here's an example:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.rtdbOncreate = functions.database.ref('/foo/{bar}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
  ... // your code logic
})
```

If you're deploying an app to Cloud Functions, I wouldn't recommend uploading a service account as other people who have access to your project might see it, once they view your function's source code in the console.

For additional reference, see [getting started with Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).

Comment: Hi @fkvestak. I still want to help. I understand that you're having problems migrating your function on supported runtimes. However, claiming that the official documentation being always wrong is not the right way to voice out your concern. We have a [sample quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/uppercase) that demonstrates a function that triggers on RTDB events and if you're having trouble following it, please post it in a constructive manner.

Comment: We're not perfect, but we always do our best to listen to our customers so if you found any parts of the official documentation which is not correct, please [let us know](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: I just manage to solve the problem. I completely deleted node_modules, package-lock.json and index.js. Went trough initialization process again, like I would do it the first time. Did all npm updates (firebase tools, etc.) and when i saw package.json updated, I knew I had something.

Then I followed your link and deployed a "skeleton" function just to see if it is working, it did. Then i went trough the code and edited everything, and there was few, like accessing data directly on "snap.val()" instead of "snapshot.data.val()", etc

Comment: The official example that states using "admin" package instead of functions, for defining function (functions.database.ref(...." is obviously misleading, so I don't know what is the point if something like that is in official docs but not working.

Your example worked perfectly, and now I don't even need to have service account inside a project which is nice.

Oh, and it is on nodejs12 now